# Is there a way to filter a report based on a textbox that will exclude whatever is in the textbox?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to filter a report by excluding any word in a textbox. I can do this in a frame but I can't seem to do it by itself in a textbox. The reason I am doing this, is because I would ideally like to have 3 frames with option buttons that will allow me to filter the report based on what is in the textboxes.

For example the three option buttons are associated with a textbox that will filter office titles. The three option buttons are begins with, contains and exclude. This works fine but the issue is I cannot combine multiple frames. I would want to filter something like 'begins with director but excludes senior'.

```
If Nz(Me.txtOffice, "") <> "" Then
   If Me.Frame19 = 1 Then
       stroffice = stroffice & "OFFICETITLE Like '" & Me.txtOffice & "*' AND "
       End If
    If Me.Frame19 = 2 = True Then
       stroffice = stroffice & "OFFICETITLE Like '*" & Me.txtOffice & "*' AND "
       End If
    If Me.Frame19 = 3 = True Then
       stroffice = stroffice & "OFFICETITLE Not Like '*" & Me.txtOffice & "*' AND "
       End If
```

Is there a way to have multiple frames filter a report or is there a way to have a textbox filter by excluding the word in the textbox?

Comment: 'director' and 'senior' could be data in same field - multiple records? So an entity could be both director and senior? Edit question to show sample data.

Comment: @June7 Like a senior director of informatics as opposed to director of vital statistics. All of the filters for office title are bound to the same column in a table

Answer (score 0):

I don't think

```
If Me.Frame19 = 2 = True Then
```

and

```
If Me.Frame19 = 3 = True Then
```

will ever evaluating to true, I believe VBA evaluates 3 = true first which would always be false, then you are comparing a boolean type to an object type after that.

Try:

```
If Me.Frame19.value = 1 Then
....
If Me.Frame19.value = 2 Then
...
If Me.Frame19.value = 3 Then
```

You should always specify which property of the object you are using i.e. .value or .text or .caption etc.